# Android. styling of ListPopupMenu

Tags: android, android-styles

I have inherited `ListPopupMenu` I used for show popup for items in `ListView` widget.

I use this code for creation and displaying my popup:

```
CADropDownPopupList popupMenu = new CADropDownPopupList(getActivity());
popupMenu.setAnchorView(view);
...
popupMenu.show();
```

I have styled `listPopupMenu` attribute in styles using this code:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
...
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/NoTitleAlertDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
...
    </style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/popup_background</item>
    </style>
```

But no one style item maps to my popup. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your theme

Use PipupMenu insted of ListPopupWindow

```
<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">   
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
    </style>
```

Because ListPopupWindow style not available check issue : 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58023

Comment: why this should help? did not help. important thing that background working well, but font size and paddings and marginns dos not works

Comment: Why ListPopupWindow class ignores paddings setted in style?

Comment: I've changed parent style to `Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu` but nothing happen. Why this should help> I mean it does not matter what is a parent style, if we are changing for paddings for example.
How can I set padding explicitly in class?

Comment: Here is example of popupmenu look into n change your code : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: The example you posted demostrates simple showing PopupMenu. I have no problem with showing PopupMenu, but I face problem that I can't set up padding for ListPopupWindow from styles

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled to get styles working, but found that you can manually set properties directly on the ListPopupWindow after creating it.

```
val popup = ListPopupWindow(context, null, R.attr.listPopupWindowStyle).apply {
    setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat(context, R.drawable.bg_popup_menu))
    // ... etc ...
}
```